# ASCII Ball in Box Animation

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, animation

Write a program that displays a moving ASCII ball `*` inside a rectangle (20 by 10 chars including border). The ball must not cross the rectangle, e.g. bump off when it hits the wall. The scene must be cleared and redrawn every 0.1 seconds and the ball must move 1 char in x and y direction every frame. The shortest program written in any language wins.

**Example output (frame 1)**

```
+------------------+
|*                 |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
+------------------+
```

**Example output (frame 2)**

```
+------------------+
|                  |
| *                |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
+------------------+
```

**Example output (frame 8)**

```
+------------------+
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|       *          |
+------------------+
```

**Example output (frame 9)**

```
+------------------+
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|        *         |
|                  |
+------------------+
```

Comment: Does printing 99 newlines qualify as clearing the screen?

Comment: Not on my monitor with `1080x1920` resolution :)

Comment: related: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/110410/55735

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Ruby 1.9, 115 characters

The movement logic is quite similar to [Danko](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/1308/danko-durbic)'s [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5658/84).

This version has been tested on Linux only.

```
p=0
loop{u=(?|+?\s*18+"|
")*8
u[165-21*(7-p%14).abs-(17-p%34).abs]=?*
p+=1
puts"\e[2J",r=?++?-*18+?+,u,r
sleep 0.1}
```

Comment: With Ruby 1.9.3 under Windows 7, `puts"\e[2J"` just prints `←[2J` (and a newline) on the screen.

Comment: @r.e.s. See my edit for a version which should run on Windows (can't test it myself unfortunately).

Comment: Using ``cls`` doesn't work for me, but `system ("cls")` does.

Comment: @r.e.s. use \`cls\`.  Literal backticks.

Comment: @MarkReed - That's what I tried to write .. Anyway, it doesn't work. Windows seems to require system("cls").

Comment: damn this one's good!

Comment: you can actually go down to 118 if you put the first two lines inside the loop. this way you don't have to remove the ball from the box any more. you can also save one character by omitting the newline after `loop{`.

Comment: that's 118 in total, not 117 sorry for the confusion

Comment: @padde I'm counting 117 characters. Make sure your editor doesn't add a trailing newline.

Comment: i used vim + wc, still get 118, double checked. I guess it doesn't matter (at least not now), but hey its codegolf!

Comment: @padde Vim does indeed add a trailing newline. You can verify this by looking at the file with `hd`.

Comment: @Ventero You are right, sorry for that!

Answer (score 4):

### Powershell, 144 characters

Based on Joey's [excellent answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5655/1308), using the fact that the ball coordinates are a function of the frame index (i), so if you have something like `x=n-abs(n-(i mod (2*n)))`, x will go from 0 to n, back to 0, and so on...

```
for(){cls
($l="+$('-'*18)+")
7..0|%{$j=$_
"|$(-join(17..0|%{'* '[$j-[Math]::abs(7-$i%14)-or$_-[Math]::abs(17-$i%34)]}))|"}
$l;$i++;sleep -m 100}
```

Comment: Nice one. Although I was kinda proud of my `if(-1,18-eq$x){$a*=-1;$x+=2*$a}if(-1,8-eq$y){$b*=-1;$y+=2*$b}` which replaced four `if`s earlier ;-). I was sure there had to be a formula, though.

Answer (score 3):

### Ruby (<strike>179</strike> <strike>174</strike> 147)

**EDIT** got rid of some more chars:

```
l=?++?-*18+?++?\n
c=?|+?\s*18+?|+?\n
p=22
u=v=1
loop{f=l+c*8+l
f[p]=?*
puts"\e[2J"+f
p+=(u=f[p+u]==' '?u:-u)+21*(v=f[p+21*v]==' '?v:-v)
sleep 0.1}
```

**EDIT** shaved off some chars, now 174:

```
l="+#{'-'*18}+\n";f=l+"|#{' '*18}|\n"*8+l;x=y=u=v=1
loop{f[21*y+x]='*';$><<"\e[2J\e[f"+f;f[21*y+x]=' '
u=f[21*y+x+u]==' '?u:-u;v=f[21*(y+v)+x]==' '?v:-v
x+=u;y+=v;sleep 0.1}
```

Ungolfed:

```
l="+#{'-'*18}+\n"           # top and bottom lines 
f=l+"|#{' '*18}|\n"*8+l     # complete box as string
x=y=u=v=1                   # x,y position; u,v next move
loop {                      #
  f[21*y+x]='*'             # add ball to box
  $> << "\e[2J\e[f"+f       # clear screen and print box with ball
  f[21*y+x]=' '             # remove ball from box
  u=f[21*y+x+u]==' '?u:-u   # next move in x direction
  v=f[21*(y+v)+x]==' '?v:-v # next move in y direction
  x+=u                      # perform move
  y+=v                      # --"--
  sleep 0.1                 # .zZZ...
}                           #
```

Comment: Shouldn't `sleep .1` work too?

Comment: Nope, not in 1.9. `SyntaxError: (irb):1: no .<digit> floating literal anymore; put 0 before dot`. But i'll get back to that if i need it in the future, thanks!

Comment: If you're on 1.9 you can use char literals to shorten a few things, e.g. `?*` instead of `'*'`, etc.

Comment: Using Ruby 1.9.3 under Win7, this prints rectangles one after (below) the other, each having `←[2J←[f+------------------+` as the first line.

Comment: then change `$> << "\e[2J\e[f"+f` to `'cls';$><<f` (use backticks for `cls`)

Answer (score 3):

### Python 2, 234

I'm sure this can be golfed more, but I gotta go so here's what I have sofar. will work more on it later

```
import os,time
a,b,c,d,e,n='+- |*\n'
w=d+c*18+d+n
s=a+b*18+a+n
x,y=0,0
g,h=17,7
j,k=1,1
while 1:
 if 0>x or x>g:j*=-1;x+=j
 if 0>y or y>h:k*=-1;y+=k
 os.system('cls');print s+w*y+d+c*x+e+c*(g-x)+d+n+w*(h-y)+s;x+=j;y+=k;time.sleep(0.1)
```

note: works on Windows command console. Other operating systems may use a different command than `cls` to clear the screen, such as `clear`

Comment: does `print "\e[H\e[2J"` work on windows?

Comment: @padde - It doesn't seem to work when I run your Ruby program under Windows 7 (see my comment to your post).

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (275 <strike>283</strike>)

```
s=Array(19).join(' ');n='\n';z=Array(9).join('|'+s+'|'+n).split(n,8);
x=y=0;a=b=1;t='+'+s.replace(/ /g,'-')+'+';
setInterval(function(){u=z[y];z[y]=u.replace(eval('/( {'+x+'}) /'),'$1*');
$('#o').text(t+n+z.join('\n')+n+t);z[y]=u;x+=a;y+=b;if(!x|x==17)a=-a;if(!y|y==7)b=-b},100)
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eKcfu/2/

I wrote this up pretty quickly so I'm sure there's still quite a bit of room for improvement.  Suggestions are welcome :)

**Edit 1**: Remove unnecessary separate function call, embed directly in `setInterval`.

Answer (score 2):

#### PowerShell, 184 <s>185</s> <s>215</s>

Only semi-golfed as my brain isn't working properly when I'm sick ...

A few nice tricks in it, though.

```
for($a=$b=1){cls
($l="+$('-'*18)+")
0..7|%{$j=$_
"|$(-join(0..17|%{'* '[$j-$y-or$_-$x]}))|"}
$l
$x+=$a;$y+=$b
if(-1,18-eq$x){$a*=-1;$x+=2*$a}if(-1,8-eq$y){$b*=-1;$y+=2*$b}sleep -m 100}
```

[Edit]: Looping over the field is much shorter.

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 212 characters

```
import System
main=mapM_ f$s 19`zip`s 9
s n=[2..n]++[n-1,n-2..3]++s n
f p=r"clear">>putStr(unlines[[" |-+*"!!(19#i+2*(9#j)+4*e((i,j)==p))|i<-[1..20]]|j<-[1..10]])>>r"sleep 0.1"
b#n=e$n<2||n>b
e=fromEnum
r=system
```

Uses a more functional approach for calculating the coordinates, by making the infinite sequence for each coordinate separately and then zipping them together (lines 2 and 3). The rest is drawing code.

Answer (score 2):

### QBasic (QB64), <s>178</s> 173 bytes

```
a$="+------------------+
?a$
for c=1to 8
?"|                  |
next
?a$
do
x=19-abs(17-(i mod 34))
y=9-abs(7-(i mod 14))
locate y,x
?"*
_delay .1
locate y,x
?" "
i=i+1
loop
```

-5 bytes thanks to DLosc

Comment: Some more golfs I just noticed: the side-wall print statement can be `?"|"SPC(18)"|` (unfortunately, using `STRING$` to generate the hyphens doesn't save any bytes); you don't need parentheses around the `mod` expressions; you've got an unnecessary double quote after the space on the third-last line; and, finally, I suspect you can save bytes by `CLS`ing and redrawing the whole box each time through the loop.

Answer (score 1):

### Perl 5, 141 characters

```
print"\e[H\e[2J",$h="+"."-"x18 ."+
",(map{"|".$"x$q,(abs$t%14-7)-$_?$":"*",$"x(17-$q),"|
"}0..7),$h,select'','','',0.1while$q=abs$t++%34-17,1
```

Does not start on the upper left corner as the example output does, but that is not stated as a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby 1.9, 162 characters

35 chars shy of @Ventero's answer, but I was impressed that I could get it down this far while still using a relatively straightforward approach to the actual logic.  The ^[ is a literal ESC (1 char).

```
x=y=0
v=h=1
s=' '
loop{puts"^[[2J"+b="+#{?-*18}+",*(0..7).map{|i|"|#{i!=y ?s*18:s*x+?*+s*(17-x)}|"},b
y+=v
y+=v*=-1if y<0||y>7
x+=h
x+=h*=-1if x<0||x>17
sleep 0.1}
```

Answer (score 1):

### R, 233 characters

```
s=c("\n+",rep("-",18),"+");for (j in 1:8){cat(s,sep="");cat(rep(c("\n|",rep("",17),"|"),j-1));cat(c("\n|",rep(" ",j-1),"*",rep(" ",18-j),"|"),sep="");cat(rep(c("\n|",rep("",17),"|"),8-j));cat(s,sep="");Sys.sleep(0.1);system("clear")}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Another bash entry - <s>213</s> 204 chars**

Not really a prize winner, but it was fun nonetheless. It uses vt100 char sequences for the drawing. (the code reported here uses 215 chars for readability, 2 chars can be removed by escaping, e.g. '*' -> \*

```sh
e(){ printf "\e[$1";}
e 2J;e H
h='+------------------+'
echo $h
for((;++j<9;));do printf '|%18s|\n';done
echo $h
e '3;2H*'
while :;do
e 'D '
((i/17%2))&&e D||e C
((++i/7%2))&&e A||e B
e 'D*'
sleep .1
done
```

Answer (score 1):

## Powershell, 139 bytes

*Inspired by Danko Durbić's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5658/80745).*

```powershell
for(){cls
,"+$('-'*18)+
"*2-join("|$(' '*18)|
"*8-replace"^(\W{$(21*[Math]::abs(7-$i%14)+[Math]::abs(17-$i++%34))}.) ",'$1*')
sleep -m 100}
```

This script uses the `-replace` operator to draw `*` inside the rectangle.

Less golfed script to explain how it works:

```powershell
for(){
    cls
    $y=[Math]::abs(7-$i%14)
    $x=[Math]::abs(17-$i++%34)
    $b="+$('-'*18)+`n"
    $m="|$(' '*18)|`n"*8-replace"^(\W{$(21*$y+$x)}.) ",'$1*'
    ,$b*2-join($m)          # draw it
    sleep -m 100
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Bash 278  <strike>300, 296</strike>

```
h="+------------------+"
w="|                  |"
g(){
echo -e "\e[$2;$1H$3"
}
g 1 1 $h
for i in {1..8}
do
echo "$w"
done
echo $h
x=4
y=4
p=1
q=1
for((;;))
do
((x==19&&p==1||x==2&&p==-1))&&p=-$p
((y==9&&q==1||y==2&&q==-1))&&q=-$q
x=$((x+p))
y=$((y+q))
g $x $y \*
sleep .1
g $x $y " "
done
```

The \e in the line `echo -e "\e[$2;$1H$3"` can be produced by

```
echo -e "\x1b"
```

to replace it. As binary 0x1b it is 3 chars shorter; I count just 1 for "\e", because only the layouting software forces me to use `\e`.

Comment: An anonymous user suggested edits to remove the `$` symbols inside `((...))` and replace `x=$(($x+$p))` with `((x+=p))` and similarly on the following line. (They also suggested using `\e` for the escape character).

Comment: I would suggest in addition that `\*` might work as a replacement for `"*"`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Thanks to the anonymous user. I incorporated suggestion no 1, and use no 2 in modified form, and yours.

Comment: @userunknown: You're rep of `1,337` needs to be permanently locked in place :P

Comment: @mellamokb: I would prefer 0xCAFE, #5CA7A or -32768.

Comment: @mellamokb: It's gone.

Answer (score 0):

## TI Basic, <s>169</s> 167 bytes

```
1→X
1→Y
1→S
1→T
While 1
ClrHome
Output(Y,X,"*
S(X>1 and X<20)+(X=1)-(X=20→S
T(Y>1 and Y<10)+(Y=1)-(Y=10→T
X+S→X
Y+T→Y
For(N,1,20,19
For(O,1,10,9
Output(O,N,"+
End
End
For(N,2,19
For(O,1,10,9
Output(O,N,"-
End
End
For(O,2,9
Output(O,1,"|
Output(O,20,"|
End
End
```

Horribly slow, but it works.

Comment: `(X=20)→S` can be `(X=20→S`, and you can take advantage of Ans to save a few bytes in the final For( loop. I'm positive lines 8 and 9 can be golfed, but I'm not sure how at the moment.

Comment: @M.I.Wright Where would I put the Ans?

Comment: `"| \ Output(O,1,Ans \ Output(O,20,Ans` should work.

Comment: @M.I.Wright But isn't that replacing a two character string with a three character string? And adding the two character string above it, making it +4?

Comment: What do you mean? `Ans` is a [one-byte token](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/one-byte-tokens), typed with `2nd` `(-)`. That'll end up saving one byte, since the `|` token is two bytes on the calculator.

Comment: @M.I.Wright Is there an online byte counter anywhere? I was just going off of character count.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25175/discussion-between-m-i-wright-and-phase).

Comment: You can golf this using http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/82847/ti-basic-bouncing-ball-animation

Comment: `dim(identity(1->A
While 1
Ans->B
Ans+∟A->A
ClrHome
∟Bcos(πʳ(Ans=1 or Ans>{19,9
For(N,1,20
For(O,1,10
Output(O,N,sub("* |-+",2+(N=1 or N=20)+2not(fPart(log(O))-min(Ans={O,N
End
End
End`

should be significantly shorter. Sorry about the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, <s>196 186</s> 148 bytes

I removed avoiding an integer overflow to save 6 bytes. It will run for 29 billion years before overflow; still 6.8 years on a 32 bit system. I´d say that´s acceptable.

Calculating the position instead of adjusting it saved a lot, preparing the complete template at once another lot.

```php
for(;++$i;$s[-3-21*abs($i%14-7)-abs($i%34-17)]="*",print$f(_,9e5,"
").$s.$z,usleep(1e5))$s=($f=str_pad)($z=$f("+",19,"-")."+
",189,$f("|",19)."|
");
").$z;
```

Run with `-nr`. Requires PHP 7.1.

**breakdown**:

```php
for(;++$i;      # infinite loop:
                    # 2. set asterisk at appropriate position
    $s[-3-21*abs($i%14-7)-abs($i%34-17)]="*";
                    # 3. clear screen: print 900k newlines
    print$f(_,9e5*0+2,"\n")
            .$s.$z, # 4. print field
    usleep(1e5))    # 5. sleep 100000 microseconds
                    # 1. create template
    $s=($f=str_pad)($z=$f("+",19,"-")."+\n",189,$f("|",19)."|\n");
```