# Do the NP: find the largest clique

Tags: code-golf, graph-theory

## Background

At the time of writing this, the P vs NP problem is still unsolved, but you might have heard of [Norbert Blum's new paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.03486) claiming proof that P != NP, which is already [suspected to be erroneous](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/38832) (but we will see).

The problem discussed in this paper is the [clique problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem). At least that's what I read in a newspaper article, so correct me if I'm wrong, but in any case, I'd like you to write a program that solves the following variant:

## The task

Assume we have a large school with lots of students. Each of these students has some friends at this school. A **clique** of students is a group consisting only of students who are friends with **each other member**.

Your program will receive pairs of students who are friends as its input. From this information, the program must find the **size of the largest clique**. Students are identified by *integer IDs*.

If you prefer mathematical terms, this means you're fed the edges of an undirected graph, identified by two nodes each.

#### Input

Your input will be a non-empty list of positive integer pairs, e.g. `[[1,2],[2,5],[1,5]]`. You can take this input in any sensible form, e.g. as an array of arrays, as lines of text containing two numbers each, etc ...

#### Output

The expected output is a single number `n >= 2`: the size of the largest clique. With the example input above, the result would be `3`, as all students (`1`, `2` and `5`) are friends with each other.

#### Test cases

```
[[1,2]]
=> 2

[[1,2],[3,1],[3,4]]
=> 2

[[1,2],[2,5],[1,5]]
=> 3

[[2,5],[2,3],[4,17],[1,3],[7,13],[5,3],[4,3],[4,1],[1,5],[5,4]]
=> 4 (the largest clique is [1,3,4,5])

[[15,1073],[23,764],[23,1073],[12,47],[47,15],[1073,764]]
=> 3 (the largest clique is [23,764,1073])

[[1296,316],[1650,316],[1296,1650],[1296,52],[1650,711],[711,316],[1650,52],
 [52,711],[1296,711],[52,316],[52,1565],[1565,1296],[1565,316],[1650,1565],
 [1296,138],[1565,138],[1565,711],[138,1650],[711,138],[138,144],[144,1860],
 [1296,1860],[1860,52],[711,1639]]
=> 6 (the largest clique is [52,316,711,1296,1565,1650])
```

You can use this (stupid) [reference implementation](https://tio.run/##rVfrT9tIEP/uv2KbitROAkp4qBIpnCiCHjpKUe/QnUQRcuxNsuCsXT94FPG3c7Pet70@@HD5ANl578xvZifR@iKKXl7eExolVYzRp6KMSbqx3PcsUkJmTVpO6ILRvPcxnhOK0Zfv3y7Orw9/vzj7A21tKvLpydnR54vj06MzNBlvbnte@Zhh4CEwUUUl@rMEg1T9n3bwv@RplVmHqec5RLwnD8GnIL/wdYlWeDXD@WFaMcNtepiFESkfOUsGMhhwbjH1nls@hHkCciS29HiA85xgGivVsCSRLVDwQ4H20NPYELpLSYwGD6swSdLIF2Gyf4FwyQXS2Q2GaPaQIRjwOMgc@e84P0D4gZT@0T8nf10fH5ycXnw/EkI5LqucIi4GUTb955jbFd6SeIRej0UqKXFHRDWBa7PPPMeYyQtJ9ukK@fkNgYdx/LUumm8le7AY6bIWMnoW1mJ938AG2ttDmiJQ0Qy5JYCGeybop21JVmWVUk0dKclu24M6kekc7qD0rIRo8qV9meHwCtwWZo5UDha4FN99DmGZk3maI4k6AurjKfz7pNC6YTYSGg5JMzkspw3h4pJcre9DcSC54EhW0CHlqPPYGT6U2R2@LjLLuNEbLIEybwWPRjUunEW7blhYYM7dfFmcbpFC8zQm@/LO0B12H3ZW6Vt@8Ka7mgWNzbYrAsT4Zsbi//Atu@iY38bXKTc6aCZDMK4WqgyM0Cxo3XxmsMPA9MgulYV5gc9DkvtRSosSRcswR4MEno3AGLShLBg7zNSBIa6IQjr3mcII9dZitBb3RqgPCvB3xkAH2NtsYlXfjSfQynVIzJmkr@4QnVmiRvJCnQoj35PXYF7XIFri6PaAxuDnMCE/K@yca1HNcg43ON3S9J5@fjxIEohauO1ocG7Imh/u/pZmNb6t/GRAt23pxm66v@Hub8B95mxBFsFNoHSfrHHJ6t5SKy5v1Kyp2zywdJ5aA1feZTJtsWYwsG9t8rPX/lZ3WW2mK1KrDGPbYsPJswENZlirNguhe0tiQD8LDSgVOMyj5WmYLyCvtXADRU0YSXKW4zuSVsX/9Th0YVr5d7wJ1lvHUiKlA/vl3ke@jtdiNaPoknMiWqSiXDFgC89aSBAYS9o0mJIEbNA374GTAreicl5LxdRRVZ7H4oSe43xVMTYMUFkj2qqo8GEvx4PIeCypsXFEIvkQUIFLPxqh8Qi5BGwvFD@UjueXkW2DjFLbdIjYJo1UNs2qYlqmJdUyb4jy@7cbo89j6rdETdTXlPslSTDyWQNQ1xYUAXiBR7qmglyn78Psb1IuwbBP@pMAsss0h0N7TqgBy5HYahRp5spW65ZzGSGvaZMrE8tK7E1ptGa33Wt6mKrGaOcLssI32rF7XNa/JCQg6wOLobkzK4Y46w7WDawbrd5D2FYxq@aX@gcspMljD@EqJLReyuDq0Bx8axnA4c58hWPQXui4GTaYPEysCer30Tv4YRmtMka7u5xcwf6yHveCQKlNBAIF3uawfRS@iGlk/Kpm0zMmNGA29T4lBAOJY9f6MDWaoWOeOCY8VFdME2E6y@G2c5/H/RvqJQwQbJnjGWZ430VrSfWD9tAubGn1N/snkF/RgiwojlGS0kXg2kqkN5bG2lWz90QYPeFWlH@3F7iXkDfvQG1ESk9822xvPfX@4UJ5VpUMK/6HH/SDet8MENuWTOTaGTeXx5eXTbTjbaItbxtNPnoT@PIRTba8nZpSU4G4A@dt72U9/hc) (prints extra output with `-d` flag) for verifying the results of other test cases.

## The rules

1. Your program doesn't need a defined result on invalid input. So you can assume that:

   - you will always get **at least one pair** of IDs
   - each pair consists of two different IDs
   - no pair appears twice (swapping the places of the IDs would still be the same pair)
2. Your algorithm isn't allowed to set an upper bound on input size. Purely technical limitations and limitations set by your language/environment (like stack size, computation time, etc) are of course inevitable.
3. Standard loopholes are forbidden.
4. This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code, measured in bytes, wins.
5. If your algorithm has polynomial time complexity, you score `-1` immediately regardless of your code size, but in that case, you might want to submit your solution somewhere else. ;)

Comment: I would recommend removing rule 5, as it means that some people will score `-1` regardless of the length of their code. You could however offer imaginary bonus points.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I bet nobody will be able to claim rule 5 ;)

Comment: I can almost guarantee that there will be someone who will do it (or try to), so it would simply be safer to remove it. If you want to reward people for doing it, you can offer a [bounty](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to the shortest answer that does it it polynomial time.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing if someone does it, the `-1` is [well deserved](http://www.claymath.org/millennium-problems/p-vs-np-problem) ;)

Comment: For reference, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem, specifically "Finding maximum cliques in arbitrary graphs"

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing If somebody managed to prove that P = NP, them having the automatic lowest score on a code golf problem is the least of our concerns. That said, Rule 5 doesn't really contribute much to the challenge, so I agree that it should be removed.

Comment: @Mego it merely contributes a *joke* and a tiny bonus to the 1M offered by CMI.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I still suggest removing it. That way a thousand-byte solution in polynomial time (assuming it's possible) would get a score of -1.

Comment: Well, I won't, in favor of the few people having some sense of "scientific humor". Please don't comment more suggestions concerning this, thanks :)

Comment: Can we assume that each edge is in sorted order?

Comment: @Mnemonic no, as seen in the test cases...

Comment: @Mnemonic If you are to assume that then you're going to assume one-way friendships...?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer They're undirected edges.  Order shouldn't matter.  But I could save two bytes if I didn't have to sort the indices.

Comment: @Mnemonic it was a joke btw...if you assume input is like `[A is a friend of B, where A <= B, ...]` but not vice versa then you're assuming one-way friendship

Comment: Could we take the input as an adjacency matrix?

Comment: @miles a "sensible form" is of course open to some creative ideas ... but the input should be pairs of friends. I'd say an adjacency matrix is too far from that, so no, sorry.

Comment: We need a fastest-code version of this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>15 18</s>  16 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/Code-page)

+3 bytes to fix bugs in my method.
-2 bytes thanks to miles (noting that **n×(n-1)÷2 = nC2**)

```
ẎQL©c2⁼Lȧ®
ŒPÇ€Ṁ
```

A monadic link taking the list of friendships (edges) and returning an integer.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hrr5An0Mrk40eNe7xObH80Dquo5MCDrc/alrzcGfD////o6MNTXUMDcyNY3WijYx1zM1MIAyokKGRjok5kDYx1zE0BfGBwmBFsQA)** forms the power-set of the edges in memory so is inefficient both in space and time (yep,that's **O(2<sup>n</sup>)** folks)!

#### How?

```
ẎQL©c2⁼Lȧ® - Link 1, isClique?: list, edges  e.g. [[1,3],[2,3],[3,4],[4,1],[4,2],[2,1]]
Ẏ          - tighten                              [ 1,3 , 2,3 , 3,4 , 4,1 , 4,2 , 2,1 ]
 Q         - de-duplicate (gets unique ids)          [1,3,2,4]
  L        - length (get number of people involved)  4
   ©       - (copy to the register)
    c2     - combinations of 2 (z-choose-2)          6
       L   - length (of edges)                       6
      ⁼    - equal?                                  1
         ® - recall value from register              4
        ȧ  - logical and                             4
           - (Note: the number of edges of a clique of size n is n*(n-1) and we're
           -  guaranteed no repeated edges and that all edges are two distinct ids)

ŒPÇ€Ṁ - Link: list of lists, edges
ŒP    - power-set (all possible sets of edges (as lists))
  Ç€  - call last link (1) as a monad for €ach
    Ṁ - maximum
```

Comment: Wow, explanation when you have time please

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I agree. I can probably add code to salvage...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64844/discussion-between-erik-the-outgolfer-and-jonathan-allan).

Comment: [16 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98t0OfQymQjW5/D0w@t4zo6KeBw@6OmNQ93Nvz//z862kjHNFYHSBoDSRMdQ3MgZQjmmOsYgihTqAxUHixtChY3iY0FAA)

Comment: @miles - nice, I just spent a while trying to get a 15 from that, I feel like it should be possible!

Comment: @JonathanAllan: "*I just spent a while trying to get a 15 from that*" if transforming the list of pairs to a flat list is all `Ẏ` does, you can drop it. Another answer already uses flat lists as input and I still consider this "sensible": the pairs are just implicated.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Without pairs in the input the power-set would be no good for purpose and the length "(of edges)" would need to be halved, so I cant get rid of the tighten.

Comment: @JonathanAllan ahh, ok :)

Answer (score 13):

## Mathematica, 34 bytes

```
Tr[1^#&@@FindClique[#<->#2&@@@#]]&
```

Basically [FindClique](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindClique.html) does the job and "finds a largest clique in the graph g."
All the other stuff is converting input-list into graph

**Input**

> [{{2, 5}, {2, 3}, {4, 17}, {1, 3}, {7, 13}, {5, 3}, {4, 3}, {4, 
>      1}, {1, 5}, {5, 4}}]

**Output**

> 4

**Input**

> [{{1296, 316}, {1650, 316}, {1296, 1650}, {1296, 52}, {1650, 
>      711}, {711, 316}, {1650, 52}, {52, 711}, {1296, 711}, {52, 
>      316}, {52, 1565}, {1565, 1296}, {1565, 316}, {1650, 1565}, {1296, 
>      138}, {1565, 138}, {1565, 711}, {138, 1650}, {711, 138}, {138, 
>      144}, {144, 1860}, {1296, 1860}, {1860, 52}, {711, 1639}}]

**Output**

> 6

*thanx @Kelly Lowder for -10 bytes*

Comment: Of course Mathematica has a builtin for this.

Comment: Shave off 10 Bytes with `Tr[1^#&@@FindClique[#<->#2&@@@#]]&`

Comment: `FindClique` ಠ___ಠ

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 20 bytes

```
ŒPẎ€µQL’=ċÐ€`ẠµÐfṪQL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opICHu/oeNa05tDXQ51HDTNsj3YcnALkJD3ctOLT18IS0hztXBfr8//8/OtpIxzRWB0gaA0kTHUNzIGUI5pjrGIIoU6gMVB4sbQoWN4mNBQA)

Of course this doesn't deserve the million :p

This would've beat Pyth, if not for the `µ(...)µ` and 2-byte `Ðf`.

Comment: Amazing. I may as well give up now.

Comment: @FelixPalmen brute force :p

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I didn't mean the runtime of the code ;)

Comment: @FelixPalmen I mean, brute force approach doesn't need much thinking :p

Comment: Gives a *MemoryError* with the largest test-case :( Of course still valid, this is a "technical limitation" -- but just out of curiosity, is there a way to increase available resources with jelly?

Comment: @FelixPalmen Nope, not Jelly alone.

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 36 bytes

```
[:>./](#(]*[=2!])#@~.@,)@#~2#:@i.@^#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYzBCsIwEETv/YqRvbQi0WzSBgKV/EeNHsSiXvoH/fW4G/CgZZcd9g0z71JmjBFTPJtjbqnN@2nkXe4orSYdukQrU0wvk67UNI/7c8GMGyNfYMEbACfXwW8NRi/a/xoKNeNhQw3KdcKUVKoRmf8@qToFB5bA4FXqaxk@6H59MUv5AA)

Runs in time *O*(2<sup>*n*</sup>) where *n* is the number of pairs.

A faster solution for 65 bytes is

```
3 :'$>{._2{~.@((+.&(e.&y)&<|.)@(-.,-.~)&>/#&,/:~@~.@,&.>/)~^:a:y'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU7bDoIwDH33K5poBkQY7gouSPgQozFGY3zx2Wj4dWwLGIVs7c5lp9u9666wC2AgRKv6JY/61comjtdSxBcpnomo3jJp4kymmWwTUedLkeahbfBWKmSdJ@0hnMIzWiwu59sDrnDUUO1BgZ4J@IjCsnNDg8PT/RskUsaCKjiI3aBGCqsUwTWdh6M2hQGNAW/pYKo02IL26KM5CeqtB6M8KO82PSCFGSOne1IoxfW9iwZukvgeAeRkU8R5NzQeR@ib/NFNObAR8Dwi45tMqKztq/TDz3pEbfyHN9uu@wA)

### Explanation

```
[:>./](#(]*[=2!])#@~.@,)@#~2#:@i.@^#  Input: list of pairs
                                   #  Length
                           2      ^   2^n
                               i.@    Range [0, 2^n)
                            #:@       Binary
                         #~           Copy
      (                )@             For each
                      ,                 Flatten
                   ~.@                  Unique
                 #@                     Length
        (       )                       Dyad with RHS at previous and LHS as next
               ]                          Get RHS
             2!                           Binomial coefficient, choose 2
            =                             Equals
           [                              Get LHS
          *                               Times
         ]                                Get RHS
       #                                Length
[:>./                                 Reduce using maximum
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 180 bytes

```python
G=input()
m=0
L=len
for i in range(2**L(G)):
 u=[];p=sum([G[j]for j in range(L(G))if 2**j&i],u)
 for j in p:u+=[j][j in u:]
 m=max(m,L(u)*all(p.count(j)==L(u)-1for j in u))
print m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYtBCoMwFET3OUVWJbFpaWxFsPy1G28QspCibcTEYP3Qnj6NQexmhpl547/La3J5CDUY53FhnFi4kAbGzpF@mqmhxtG5dc@O5VnWsJrzilAEpe8e3miZqtWgV3L4kwkzPY2P4WC0QE7ojvgKjxA/KiWsNKEWbPthVjQMedaOI/Pnx4RuYQMHWMuT3O/IOfGzcQu1ISiVi0KLqNeoNyHLaDKFUsjVim3Z9jQXqb9p/QM)

-2 thanks to [shooqie](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/51530/shooqie).
-1 thanks to [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder).
-3 thanks to [recursive](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/527/recursive).

Comment: You can save two bytes by assigning `len` to a variable

Comment: [183 bytes](https://tio.run/##RYzBCoMwEETv@YqcyiZNi1pFsOzZi38QcpCibcTEYA20X29jEHuZYefNrPsur8lm61qjts4vwIjBhDQ4dpb000w11ZbOrX12kHHeQM1YRahHqe4O396ArOWgtubwb8aa7mlYDCethGeEHhVX@TOGDU84h5hs2KBpP2BEA57xdhzBXR@TtwsMDHELL@nxwTNG3KztQs26SpmJQomgt6C5SMtgaTxKkW5W7GTnERcxz5X6AQ). `(x not in y)` means `0**(x in y)`.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder I knew there was a way to shorten it! Thanks!

Comment: I have never used that before, just a trick that crossed thorugh my mind a couple of days ago but couldn't find a use to it yet.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Doesn't matter, if it works then why not? :D BTW you can also replace `0**` with `-~-`.

Comment: I believe `[j]*0**(j in u)` can be replaced with `[j][j in u:]` for -3.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Now this is strange: This gave me again `2` with my `msys2` installation of python on windows for the last test case ... but testing it on a linux machine (some older Debian), it indeed returned `6`! Just wanted to let you know, I guess it's the same algorithm as the other answer? Looks like a strange case of "code ok, bug in execution environment" (or maybe *undefined behavior*, but I didn't think python had this concept ...)

Comment: @FelixPalmen Well, to be honest, I've never tried that with an "msys2" implementation of python or anything...on windows (which I rarely use) I just have the normal python installation.

Comment: @recursive hey that's clever!

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer it just simplifies things as it comes with a linux-like package manager -- should be the same code though ... well, sorry for the hassle, it really seems to be buggy.

Comment: You should be able to assign `range` to a var as well e.g. `R=range` which will save 6 bytes.

Comment: @Scironic Tried that...won't save any.

Comment: Damn I miscounted - you are right.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 19 bytes

```
l{ef.AqLtl{T/LTTsMy
```

[Try it here.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=l%7Bef.AqLtl%7BT%2FLTTsMy&input=%5B%5B15%2C1073%5D%2C%5B23%2C764%5D%2C%5B23%2C1073%5D%2C%5B12%2C47%5D%2C%5B47%2C15%5D%2C%5B1073%2C764%5D%5D&debug=0)

Answer (score 2):

## [6502 machine code](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/6502_Assembly) (C64), <strike>774</strike> 703 bytes

(I just **had** to do this, my C64 can do everything ... hehe)

**hexdump:**

```
00 C0 A9 00 A2 08 9D 08 00 CA 10 FA A2 04 9D FB 00 CA 10 FA 20 54 C0 B0 20 AD 
C9 C2 AE CA C2 20 92 C1 B0 31 8D 31 C0 AD CB C2 AE CC C2 20 92 C1 B0 23 A2 FF 
20 FE C1 90 DB 20 6A C2 20 C1 C1 B0 05 20 6A C2 50 F6 A5 FB 8D D3 C2 20 43 C1 
A9 CD A0 C2 20 1E AB 60 A2 00 86 CC 8E 61 C0 20 E4 FF F0 FB A2 FF C9 0D F0 10 
E0 0B 10 0C 9D BD C2 20 D2 FF E8 8E 61 C0 D0 E5 C6 CC A9 20 20 D2 FF A9 0D 20 
D2 FF A9 00 9D BD C2 AA BD BD C2 F0 5C C9 30 30 0E C9 3A 10 0A 9D CD C2 E8 E0 
06 F0 4C D0 E9 C9 20 D0 46 A9 00 9D CD C2 E8 8E BC C0 20 EB C0 AD D3 C2 8D C9 
C2 AD D4 C2 8D CA C2 A2 FF A0 00 BD BD C2 F0 0F C9 30 30 21 C9 3A 10 1D 99 CD 
C2 C8 E8 D0 EC A9 00 99 CD C2 20 EB C0 AD D3 C2 8D CB C2 AD D4 C2 8D CC C2 18 
60 38 60 A2 FF E8 BD CD C2 D0 FA A0 06 88 CA 30 0A BD CD C2 29 0F 99 CD C2 10 
F2 A9 00 99 CD C2 88 10 F8 A9 00 8D D3 C2 8D D4 C2 A2 10 A0 7B 18 B9 53 C2 90 
02 09 10 4A 99 53 C2 C8 10 F2 6E D4 C2 6E D3 C2 CA D0 01 60 A0 04 B9 CE C2 C9 
08 30 05 E9 03 99 CE C2 88 10 F1 30 D2 A2 06 A9 00 9D CC C2 CA D0 FA A2 08 A0 
04 B9 CE C2 C9 05 30 05 69 02 99 CE C2 88 10 F1 A0 04 0E D3 C2 B9 CE C2 2A C9 
10 29 0F 99 CE C2 88 10 F2 CA D0 D9 C8 B9 CD C2 F0 FA 09 30 9D CD C2 E8 C8 C0 
06 F0 05 B9 CD C2 90 F0 A9 00 9D CD C2 60 85 0A A4 09 C0 00 F0 11 88 B9 D5 C2 
C5 0A D0 F4 8A D9 D5 C3 D0 EE 98 18 60 A4 09 E6 09 D0 01 60 A5 0A 99 D5 C2 8A 
99 D5 C3 98 99 D5 C4 18 60 A6 0B E4 09 30 01 60 BD D5 C5 C5 0B 30 09 A9 00 9D 
D5 C5 E6 0B D0 E9 A8 FE D5 C5 8A 29 01 D0 02 A0 00 BD D5 C4 59 D5 C4 9D D5 C4 
59 D5 C4 99 D5 C4 5D D5 C4 9D D5 C4 A9 00 85 0B 18 60 A8 A5 0C D0 08 A9 20 C5 
0D F0 21 A5 0C 8D 1E C2 8D 21 C2 A5 0D 09 60 8D 1F C2 49 E0 8D 22 C2 8C FF FF 
8E FF FF E6 0C D0 02 E6 0D 18 60 86 0E 84 0F A5 0D 09 60 8D 54 C2 49 E0 8D 5F 
C2 A6 0C CA E0 FF D0 10 AC 54 C2 88 C0 60 10 02 18 60 8C 54 C2 CE 5F C2 BD 00 
FF C5 0E F0 04 C5 0F D0 E0 BD 00 FF C5 0E F0 04 C5 0F D0 D5 38 60 A2 00 86 FC 
86 FD 86 FE BD D5 C4 A8 A6 FE E4 FC 10 11 BD D5 C7 AA 20 2B C2 90 14 E6 FE A6 
FE E4 FC D0 EF A6 FD BD D5 C4 A6 FC E6 FC 9D D5 C7 E6 FD A6 FD E4 09 D0 16 A6 
FB E4 FC 10 0F A2 00 BD D5 C7 9D D5 C6 E8 E4 FC D0 F5 86 FB 60 A0 00 84 FE F0 
B5
```

#### [Online demo](https://vice.janicek.co/c64/#%7B"controlPort2":"joystick","primaryControlPort":2,"keys":%7B"SPACE":"","RETURN":"","F1":"","F3":"","F5":"","F7":""%7D,"files":%7B"clique.prg":"data:;base64,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"%7D,"vice":%7B"-autostart":"clique.prg"%7D%7D)

Usage: Start with `sys49152`, then enter the pairs one per line like e.g.

```
15 1073
23 764
23 1073
12 47
47 15
1073 764
```

Backsapce **isn't** handled during input (but if you use `vice`, just copy&paste your input into the emulator). Enter an empty line to start calculation.

This is too large to post an explanatory disassembly listing here, but [you can browse the ca65-style assembly source](https://github.com/Zirias/c64clique/tree/0eb3304f7461b59ff6da74e48c30ca29f2aec8b2). The algorithm is very inefficient, it generates every possible permutation of the nodes and with each of these greedily builds a clique by checking all the edges. This allows for a *space efficiency* of **O(n)** (kind of important on a machine with this little RAM), but has **horrible** *runtime efficiency* **(*)**. The theoretical limits are up to 256 nodes and up to 8192 edges.

- -71 bytes: optimized routine for checking edges and zeropage usage

---

There's a larger (<strike>883</strike> 805 bytes) version with better features:

- visual feedback during calculation (each permutation of the nodes changes the border color)
- uses bank switching to store the edges in the RAM "hidden" by the ROMs to conserve space
- outputs the size **and** the nodes of the maximal clique found

**[Online demo](https://vice.janicek.co/c64/#%7B"controlPort2":"joystick","primaryControlPort":2,"keys":%7B"SPACE":"","RETURN":"","F1":"","F3":"","F5":"","F7":""%7D,"files":%7B"clique.prg":"data:;base64,AMCpAKIInQgAyhD6ogSd+wDKEPogX8CwIK0vw64wwyCgwbA8jTHArTHDrjLDIKDBsC6i/yAiwpDbeKkFhQGtINCFCCCOwu4g0CDPwbAFII7CUPOpB4UBWKUIjSDQIOHCYKIAhsyObMAg5P/w+6L/yQ3wEOALEAydI8Mg0v/ojmzA0OXGzKkgINL/qQ0g0v+pAJ0jw6q9I8PwXMkwMA7JOhAKnTPD6OAG8EzQ6ckg0EapAJ0zw+iOx8Ag9sCtOcONL8OtOsONMMOi/6AAvSPD8A/JMDAhyToQHZkzw8jo0OypAJkzwyD2wK05w40xw606w40ywxhgOGCi/+i9M8PQ+qAGiMowCr0zwykPmTPDEPKpAJkzw4gQ+KkAjTnDjTrDohCgexi5ucKQAgkQSpm5wsgQ8m46w245w8rQAWCgBLk0w8kIMAXpA5k0w4gQ8TDSogapAJ0yw8rQ+qIQoAS5NMPJBTAFaQKZNMOIEPGgBA45wy46w7k0wyrJECkPmTTDiBDyytDWyLkzw/D6CTCdM8PoyMAG8AW5M8OQ8KkAnTPDYIUKpAnAAPARiLk7w8UK0PSK2TvE0O6YGGCkCeYJ0AFgpQqZO8OKmTvEmJk7xRhgpgvkCTABYL07xsULMAmpAJ07xuYL0Omo/jvGiikB0AKgAL07xVk7xZ07xVk7xZk7xV07xZ07xakAhQsYYL07w405w707xI06wyBOwakzoMNMHquopQzQCKkgxQ3wIaUMjULCjUXCpQ0JoI1DwgngjUbCjP//jv//5gzQAuYNGGCGDoQPpQ0JoI14wklAjYPCpgzK4P/QEKx4wojAoBACGGCMeMLOg8K9AP/FDvAExQ/Q4L0A/8UO8ATFD9DVOGCiAIb8hv2G/r07xaim/uT8EBG9O8iqIE/CkBTm/qb+5PzQ76b9vTvFpvzm/J07yOb9pv3kCdAWpvvk/BAPogC9O8idO8fo5PzQ9Yb7YKAAhP7wtakAhf6NOsOl+405wyBOwakzoMMgHqupICDK8albIMrxpv69O8eqIAzC5v6m/uT78AepLCDK8ZDoqV0gyvGpDUzK8Q=="%7D,"vice":%7B"-autostart":"clique.prg"%7D%7D)**

**[Browse source](https://github.com/Zirias/c64clique/tree/master)**

---

**(*)** The last test case takes something between 12 and 20 hours (I was sleeping when it finally finished). The other test cases finish at worst within some minutes.

[image: Screenshot of last test case]

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 19 bytes

```
æ€˜ʒDÙg<s{γ€gQP}θÙg
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8LJHTWtOzzk1yeXwzHSb4upzm4H89MCA2nM7gAL//0dHG@mYxuoASWMgaaJjaA6kDMEccx1DEGUKlYHKg6VNweImsbEA)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64828/discussion-between-erik-the-outgolfer-and-felix-palmen).

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 28 bytes

```
l{sSef<T.{SMQm.{ft{T.Cd2yS{s
```

[Try it online](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=l%7BsSef%3CT.%7BSMQm.%7Bft%7BT.Cd2yS%7Bs&input=[%282%2C5%29%2C%282%2C3%29%2C%284%2C17%29%2C%281%2C3%29%2C%287%2C13%29%2C%285%2C3%29%2C%284%2C3%29%2C%284%2C1%29%2C%281%2C5%29%2C%285%2C4%29]&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
l{sSef<T.{SMQm.{ft{T.Cd2yS{s
                         S{sQ  Get the distinct nodes in the (implicit) input.
                        y      Take every subset.
             m      .Cd2       Get the pairs...
                ft{T           ... without the [x, x] pairs...
              .{               ... as sets.
     f<T                        Choose the ones...
        .{  Q                   ... which are subsets of the input...
          SM                    ... with edges in sorted order.
    e                           Take the last element (largest clique).
l{sS                            Get the number of distinct nodes.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>162</strike> 159 bytes

```python
lambda x,f=lambda x:{i for s in x for i in s}:len(f(x))if all([(y,z)in x or(z,y)in x for y in f(x)for z in f(x)if y<z])else max(c(x.difference({y}))for y in x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzNCsIwEITvPkXAyy4sYvpjoeiTqIdaEwzEVFoPSYvPXrOx6mlnduabR3jeOpfP7eE02@Z@uTbCkz58ZT0ZobteDMI44ZM0LIdXbZUDDR7RaNFYC0cINGKqdT2MFPCHBEa4y2b8msiF/XhGZQcl7o2HFvzmarRWvXKtgim8EH@4x/nRG/eMrQlkSXJb5UiQ5VTtio9YXjKjooq3qEiW7OM7leLcav0fyYjTjJgpSDIik4kcn3JJljzFZfqnqfkN)

Function c takes vertices in the form of a set of <strike>sorted</strike> tuples ({(x,y),...} where x is less than y). <strike>A function called "entry" is in the TIO header to test with data in list of unsorted lists format</strike>. If clique, returns length. If not clique, returns max clique size of vertices, minus a vertice for each vertice in vertices. Exceeds time on last test case in TIO

Update: "or(z,y)in x" portion added to remove dependency on sortedness
"f=lambda x:{i for s in x for i in s}" instead of itertools.chain wrapped in set.

-minus 3 bytes thanks to @Jonathan Allen

Comment: You [may not assume the input edges are sorted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/141053/do-the-np-find-the-largest-clique#comment345730_141053).

Comment: Aside - you do not need to name `c`, so can remove `c=` (you'd need to put ``c=\`` at the end of the header and place the `lambda` at the top of the code block for TIO)

Comment: Also [you can get rid of `s`](https://tio.run/##VU/RasMwDHzPV@hRKqaQtaEwli/J8uAmMjU4drA9sFP67ZkT2rK93HG6OyTNOd6cPa1so8@tkdN1lJA@BwwcMf7MhjE4H3nETKSchwzaQiKqhvZ7fecNW7wfFB4SPUgrkMZgh1kstKXhVXxFNr380aWRv5ae2ASGSSYcMB1HrRR7tgPjPT/@ba/0NJerQEf20TkTQAbQlWr1cbhJbdfZaxtxfwq77kM0vSh4KngW9aVQvYuLqDdqns7T3@1mn5/7nmj9BQ) and replace `s(...)` with `{*...}` allowing the removal of some spaces too.

Comment: @JonathanAllan thanks, sortedness fixed

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 28 bytes

```
œ^e³;U¤
Œcç/Ðfœ|Ṣ¥/€QµÐĿ-ịḢL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///o5LjUQ5utQw8t4To6Kfnwcv3DE9KOTq55uHPRoaX6j5rWBB7aenjCkf26D3d3P9yxyOf////R0YZGlmY6xoZmsTrRhmamBjAmSBTEh7FNjWAKzA0NgUwgiawLLG1qBJUE64AwgWIQZUCGoamZKUgWSOmAlMDYSObAlICtN7aAq0YwoTYYW8CcB3IJVB4kaGICYpmY6BhamMFdD2MDKYhTwZrMjC1jYwE)

Faster solution that is able to solve the last test case in a second on TIO.

Comment: And what complexity does this have? If it's anything lower than **O(2ⁿ)** then it deserves $1,000,000.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer, you are wrong, there are algorithms which have **O(1.1888ⁿ)** runtime.

Comment: Adding to that, to be worth a million, the `n` may only appear in the bases :)

Comment: @FelixPalmen, or it can' t. Anyway, for million one of two statements must be proved.

Comment: @rus9384 "it can't" would need proof --- while finding a polynomial algorithm here would be instant proof that P=NP (the problem is NP complete) :)

Comment: @FelixPalmen, of course it would, but it can't be heuristics for the proof.

Comment: I believe this is O(1.414^n). You can see worse performance when the input is a complete graph.

Answer (score 1):

## Java + Guava 23.0, 35 + 294 = 329 bytes

```java
import com.google.common.collect.*;
a->{int l=0,o=1,c,z=a.size();for(;o>0&l<z;){o=0;c:for(Iterable<int[]>s:Sets.combinations(a,l*(l+1)/2)){Multiset<Integer>m=TreeMultiset.create();for(int[]x:s){m.add(x[0]);m.add(x[1]);}c=m.elementSet().size();for(int e:m.elementSet())if (m.count(e)!=c-1)continue c;l+=o=1;break;}}return z<3?2:l;}
```

This algorithm is not graphing, but instead is generating all combinations of pairs, of a specific size. I feed all pair-combinations into a multiset and check that they all have the expected size (the number of unique entries - 1). If they do, I found a clique and I go look for a bigger one.

From the Guava library, I use the new `combinations` method, and the tool-collection-type `Multiset`.

## Ungolfed

```java
import com.google.common.collect.*;
import java.util.function.*;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ToIntFunction<java.util.Set<int[]>> f
        = a -> {
          int l = 0, o = 1, c, z = a.size();
          for (; o > 0 & l < z;) {
            o = 0;
            c:
            for (Iterable<int[]> s : Sets.combinations(a, l * (l + 1) / 2)) {
              Multiset<Integer> m = TreeMultiset.create();
              for (int[] x : s) {
                m.add(x[0]);
                m.add(x[1]);
              }
              c = m.elementSet().size();
              for (int e : m.elementSet()) {
                if (m.count(e) != c - 1) {
                  continue c;
                }
              }
              l += o = 1;
              break;
            }
          }
          return z < 3 ? 2 : l;
        };
    int[][][] tests = {
      {{1, 2}},
      {{1, 2}, {3, 1}, {3, 4}},
      {{1, 2}, {2, 5}, {1, 5}},
      {{2, 5}, {2, 3}, {4, 17}, {1, 3}, {7, 13}, {5, 3}, {4, 3}, {4, 1}, {1, 5}, {5, 4}},
      {{15, 1073}, {23, 764}, {23, 1073}, {12, 47}, {47, 15}, {1073, 764}},
      {{1296, 316}, {1650, 316}, {1296, 1650}, {1296, 52}, {1650, 711}, {711, 316}, {1650, 52}, {52, 711}, {1296, 711}, {52, 316}, {52, 1565}, {1565, 1296}, {1565, 316}, {1650, 1565}, {1296, 138}, {1565, 138}, {1565, 711}, {138, 1650}, {711, 138}, {138, 144}, {144, 1860}, {1296, 1860}, {1860, 52}, {711, 1639}}
    };
    for (int[][] test : tests) {
      java.util.Set<int[]> s = new java.util.HashSet<int[]>();
      for (int[] t : test) {
        s.add(t);
      }
      System.out.println(f.applyAsInt(s));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd be **very** surprised, see [Finding maximum cliques in arbitrary graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem#Finding_maximum_cliques_in_arbitrary_graphs) -- but it'll take me a while to analyze this code, I'm not too familiar with Java :)

Comment: @FelixPalmen  I liked this challenge so my answer will stay no matter what, but I'm totally okay with removing the "-1" if it's not a polynomial complexity. Then I should probably go review some books :P

Comment: "*Combination of size `x` is polynomial*" <- are you sure? I guess [that's the method used](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Sets.java#L1666). The return value is an `AbstractSet` with an iterator, and the following `for` loop will call this iterator `x!` times if I'm not mistaken...

Comment: Correction: as long as `x < n` (with `n` being the complete size of the input set), it's `n!/(x!(n-x)!)`, still not polynomial :)

Comment: @FelixPalmen You're most likely right. Also, are you saying that if I make a `combinations` method that's `X^n` (which is entirely possible), I can get it? Meanwhile, I remove my claim of the "-1".

Comment: I don't think so because even with a function creating all the combinations in advance and doing that in polynomial time, you'd still have to iterate over the result of this (which has a size up to `x!`) ... or do I misunderstand your approach here?. As already commented a few times, if you can **really** do it, you'll be rich soon ;) (the current benchmark for the problem is **O(1.888ⁿ)** )

Comment: As I said, I might have to review books to properly understand polynomial complexity :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 102 bytes

```python
def f(g):
 x=g
 while x:y=x;x=map(set,{tuple(u|v)for u in x for v in x if u^v in g})
 return len(y[0])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVDLboMwELzzFT6CtAf8hKTiS6JUqlRDkChBFFIQzbfTXWOnoepldzwzuztyNw@XayvW9d2WrIyr5Bixqagi9nWpG8um41xML1Px8dbFn3aAZRi7xsbj9y0prz0bWd2yiRG8bbAu2fjqcHVPItbbYexb1tg2nk/pOVm7vm4HPHRaOIj7OYn2BCwSuKvqP1GAxsqx7sSNFiCxKuCZ89AjA05Ne8XrfgXxf69o4GlGNiEhM2oDnuICFK1WuNXFQNqZ9ivEwYDkhgxGpwESS@@AtQiGjFMgrM9TTtbCi25ig8htNgRcG5cDG5Al4Kc9weLOy/zh/oX@gsxDPEridSIVfQJW4Ll5pA8Y2xbVDRl5wL9YfwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>790 778 757 748 731 687 642</s> 632 bytes

```c
typedef struct F F;typedef struct{int c,p;F**m;}g;struct F{int d;g f;};g*a,S,y,q,*x=&y,*p=&q,Q;A(g*g,F*s){g->c++[g->m=g->c-g->p?g->m:realloc(g->m,(g->p+=32)*20)]=s;}i,c[999],b,j,k,l,*s;*B(d){s=0;for(i=S.c;i--;)s=S.m[i]->d-d?s:S.m[i];!s?s=calloc(5,4),*s=d,A(&S,s):0;s=s;}F*u,*v;E(){for(i=-1;b=++i<S.c;b&&A(x,S.m[i]))for(l=x->c;k=l--*b;b&=!k)for(j=(Q=x->m[l]->f).c;j--&&(k=Q.m[j]->d-S.m[i]->d););x->c>p->c?a=x,x=p,p=a:0;x->c=0;}main(){for(;~scanf("%d %d",&a,&b)&&A(&(u=B(a))->f,v=B(b))|~A(&v->f,u););for(E();b<S.c;)c[b]>=b?c[b++]=0:E(S.m[b]=a,S.m[i]=S.m[b],a=S.m[i=b%2*c[b]++]);for(printf("%d,",i=p->c);i--;)printf(" %d",p->m[i]->d);}
```

This is a slightly golfed version of the reference implementation. Thanks to @jdt for -5.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVJNb@JADL3zK1IkopmJsyKBZIFZg1qp3BFHlEM@IAoEmhJAIJb@dWpnoKs9jOfZzx/Pk6Runqb3@@FSLbPlyqoP@2N6sKbWVP8fuha7g5VCpadKbfUt18/Mhsh0bq30Tecqhjlc4BPUGe0LqArtT5jpV5GrHKaqltfcHaeOs6Bri4xdMtWE3dF@GZflRyrYAbaVgz1fKr8rI6z1rYB0MRwOI0hgDRsoQdVavYlMXmvs6tXHXhQ4/5XqwnW1rAluF0XkjjM3m9Qj4@mXelJjauYE0JfUAzN4FfYcajnq6poHTdUR1Em/C3k1XV1PJ@g4xR9un9j2qziDaSglZ5R4plX0BkvXVQll4MumIdYoZsxtFyUpWUkqX7uubYsNzqh@3cj7ESq11NxoXJGZxHiGM1ZQYUzCOE5b3rZxsXvo0l91Gu9Wot3JrE7WBjsGO5GszhZHfBOxlDQTTgQTKf9@UfzEgSPP4Qa0oE6anWS6SKIxJhO6HSfC7uhdsKwkwvixKRofYvOwmHR8xVWUbrpVe/oVGjXQhgJ5B2m@xZNpVFb8Go91b/e75w9Dq@eFLS8MugZwhD2DAt9Qvz2vRedfLhGB34SbPAbkM02XF4RBi43FpEE/lYZsxvQGj6wnaPr1BkYAz2sYDvT7LTqWNwgfygwiw1Ka1LA3/AY)

Slightly golfed less

```c
typedef struct F F;
// student group
typedef struct{
  int c, // count
      p; // capacity
  F**m;  // members
}g;
// student
struct F{
  int d; // id
  g f;   // friends
};
g*a,S,y,q,*x=&y,*p=&q,Q;
A(g*g,F*s){
  g->c++[g->m=g->c-g->p?g->m:realloc(g->m,(g->p+=32)*20)]=s;
}
i,c[999],b,j,k,l,*s;
*B(d){
  s=0;
  for(i=S.c;i--;)
    s=S.m[i]->d-d?s:S.m[i];
  !s?
    s=calloc(5,4),
    *s=d,
    A(&S,s)
  :
    0;
  s=s;
}
F*u,*v;
E(){
  for(i=-1;b=++i<S.c;b&&A(x,S.m[i]))
    for(l=x->c;k=l--*b;b&=!k)
      for(j=(Q=x->m[l]->f).c;j--&&(k=Q.m[j]->d-S.m[i]->d););
  x->c>p->c?
    a=x,
    x=p,
    p=a
  :
    0;
  x->c=0;
}
main(){
  for(;~scanf("%d %d",&a,&b)&&A(&(u=B(a))->f,v=B(b))|~A(&v->f,u););
  for(E();b<S.c;)
    c[b]>=b?
      c[b++]=0
    :
      E(S.m[b]=a,S.m[i]=S.m[b],a=S.m[i=b%2*c[b]++]);
  for(printf("%d,",i=p->c);i--;)
    printf(" %d",p->m[i]->d);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 17 bytes

```
l{seq#.c{sT2tySSM
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P6e6OLVQWS@5ujjEqKQyONj3///oaCMd01gdIGkMJE10DM2BlCGYY65jCKJMoTJQebC0KVjcJDYWAA)

- `SSM`: Sort each edge, then sort the edges.
- `y`: Form all subsets of edges, with each subset in sorted order. The subsets are ordered by increasing length.
- `t`: Remove the first subset, which is the empty subset, as it would cause the program to crash.
- `q#`: Filter over the subsets on the following resulting in an identical list of edges as the particular subset.
- `{sT`: Sum the list and deduplicate, giving all vertices in any of the edges. If the subset was a clique, the vertices will be in sorted order.
- `.c ... 2`: All distinct pairs of vertices, in sorted order.
- `e`: The filter returns all cliques. Take the last clique, which is the largest clique.
- `{s`: Sum and deduplicate, giving the vertices in the largest clique.
- `l`: Length of the longest clique.

Apparently, during the brief window from May 2017 to Nov. 2017, during which this challenge was posted, `sY` returned an empty list, rather than 0, as it currently does, so the `t` could have been removed for -1 byte. Before and after, this would cause a crash. See [commit 5b973af89b](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth/blob/5b973af89bbd0bf3d0a255e3d2dfffbda72c1d0b/macros.py#L983), which was the most recent commit when this challenge was posted.