# ASCII reflections in a box

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

## ASCII reflections in a box

You probably all know the [*Law of Reflection*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specular_reflection), in this challenge you'll visualize the trajectory of a ball in a box.

Related: [ASCII Ball in Box Animation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5651/ascii-ball-in-box-animation) and [ASCII Doodling: Laser in a Box](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48531/ascii-doodling-laser-in-a-box)

#### Task

You're given three integer pairs `W,H`, `x,y` and `dx,dy` - the first represents the size of the box, the second the starting position and the third pair is the direction in which the ball starts moving.

The task is to visualize the movement of the ball until it stops rolling, this happens as soon as the ball is at a position that it was before or it hits a corner.

The character `*` shall visualize the trajectory of the ball and `+` marks its final position, the rest of the box must consist of  (whitespace).

#### Examples

To lay it out a bit clearer, in these examples `_` will represent a whitespace. Also the intermediate stages are only here for clarification, you'll only need to output the last stage, these examples are `1`-indexed.

---

Given `W = 3, H = 5`, `x = 3, y = 2` and `dx = -1, dy = 1`:

```
___    ___    ___    ___
__*    __*    __*    __*
___ -> _*_ -> _*_ -> _+_
___    *__    *__    *_*
___    ___    _*_    _*_
```

- Ball starts at point `(3,2)` and
- moves in direction `(-1,1)`, hits the wall at `(1,4)` and
- gets reflected, new direction is `(1,1)`. It hits the wall again at `(2,5)`
- where it gets gets reflected. The new direction is `(1,-1)` and it hits the wall immediately at `(3,4)`,
- again it gets reflected into the direction `(-1,-1)`. It would now travel through points `(2,3),(1,2)`, reflected etc. but since it already visited the position `(2,3)` it stops there.

---

This example demonstrates, what happens if a ball hits a corner. For this let `W = 7, H = 3`, `x = 1, y = 3` and `dx = 1, dy = -1`:

```
_______    __*____    __*____    __*___+
_______ -> _*_____ -> _*_*___ -> _*_*_*_
*______    *______    *___*__    *___*__
```

- Start position is `(1,3)`,
- the ball now travels in direction `(1,-1)` until it hits the wall at `(3,1)`
- where it gets reflected into the new direction `(1,1)`.
- At `(5,3)` it gets reflected and travels into the new direction `(1,-1)`. It comes to an abrupt stop at `(7,1)` because that's a corner.

---

Given `W = 10, H = 6`, `x = 6, y = 6` and `dx = 1, dy = 1`:

```
__________    __________    ________*_    ________*_    ________*_    __*_____*_    __*_____*_
__________    _________*    _________*    _______*_*    _______*_*    _*_____*_*    _*_*___*_*
__________ -> ________*_ -> ________*_ -> ______*_*_ -> *_____*_*_ -> *_____*_*_ -> *___*_*_*_
__________    _______*__    _______*__    _____*_*__    _*___*_*__    _*___*_*__    _*___+_*__
__________    ______*___    ______*___    ____*_*___    __*_*_*___    __*_*_*___    __*_*_*___
_____*____    _____*____    _____*____    ___*_*____    ___*_*____    ___*_*____    ___*_*____
```

#### Input specification

The input consists of the three integer pairs `W,H`, `x,y` and `dx,dy`, you may take input in any format that makes most sense for your programming language and the order doesn't matter. However the accepted input must not encode more information than these pairs contain (see [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/132450/48198) answer for an example).

- `W,H >= 1`
- `x,y` are either `1`-indexed (`1 <= x <= W` and `1 <= y <= H`) or `0`-indexed (`0 <= x < W` and `0 <= y < H`), please specify what indexing you chose
- `dx,dy` are always either `-1` or `1`

Invalid input can be ignored.

#### Output specification

1. No leading whitespaces are allowed
2. Trailing whitespaces may be omitted
3. Trailing whitespaces are not allowed if they don't fit the box
4. Trailing newlines (*after* all output related lines) are allowed

Let's take the first example:

```
       (good by 2)
__*
_+     (good by 2)
*_*_   (bad by 3)
       (bad by 4)
_*_
       (good by 4)
```

#### Test cases

Assuming the input has the format `(W,H,x,y,dx,dy)` and `1`-indexing was chosen, here are some test cases (again `_` is here to represent whitespaces!):

Input: 1,1,1,1,1,1

Output:

```
+
```

Input: 3,3,3,3,1,1

Output:

```
___
___
__+
```

Input: 3,3,3,3,-1,-1

Output:

```
+__
_*_
__*
```

Input: 7,3,1,3,1,-1

Output:

```
__*___+
_*_*_*_
*___*__
```

Input: 10,6,6,6,1,1

Output:

```
__*_____*_
_*_*___*_*
*___*_*_*_
_*___+_*__
__*_*_*___
___*_*____
```

Input: 21,7,6,4,-1,-1

Output:

```
__*_______*_______*__
_*_*_____*_*_____*_*_
*___*___*___*___*___*
_*___*_*_____*_*___*_
__*___*_______+___*__
___*_*_________*_*___
____*___________*____
```

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program/function wins, but any effort is appreciated.

Comment: I suspect one of the 2D languages (Turtle?) might do really well with this challenge.

Comment: Would it be allowed to encode the four possible dx/dy values as four consecutive odd integers? How important is it that x and y are 1-indexed?

Comment: I'll drop the `1`-indexed constraint if you like(?) About that first question, not sure what you mean but it sounds ok. I guess anything that is a bijection (`{-1,1}x{-1,1} ≡ "Your space"`) would be good.

Comment: Edited in the indexing, can you be more specific on your other question?

Comment: I want to see a charcoal answer for this lol.

Comment: See my answer for what I meant about encoding dx and dy. @MagicOctopusUrn Your wish is my command!

Comment: Yeah, I don't see a problem with that.

Answer (score 8):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 50 bytes

```
ＵＯＮＮ ＪＮＮ↷ＮＷ⁼ ＫＫ«*¿¬ＫＫ«↷²¶*¿¬ＫＫ«↷²¶↷²*¿¬ＫＫ«↷²¶»»»»+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY29DoIwFEZn@hQ3nYrCIIY4ODvogMQ4ugBBaCwtQouD4dkrKEbCj0OHm@@c0ygNikgETOtjyARPyJ7nSnoqC@OCmBYMTgzY3KKDyvKz@Is2lE8rIU80SSUZTo@UshjI7q4CVpImaoEfx7dmM@GJDL@gXBK8aP8y6BWIJyTpA0av7bTQV7nwjzRtjbWfh7t7jui6M@EJb5Su0fvVqEbdtGwWrZ0VbMCFNbjarrRdshc) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes five inputs: `w`, `h`, `x`, `y`, `a`. `x` and `y` are zero-indexed. `a` represents `dx` and `dy` according to the following encoding:

```
a mod 8 == 1 => dx = 1, dy = 1
a mod 8 == 3 => dx = -1, dy = 1
a mod 8 == 5 => dx = -1, dy = -1
a mod 8 == 7 => dx = 1, dy = -1
```

Explanation:

```
ＵＯＮＮ
```

(note trailing space) Fills the background with spaces to the input width and height. (Normally each square of the background is an empty string, which is then converted to a space on output.)

```
ＪＮＮ
```

Moves the cursor to the initial coordinates.

```
↷Ｎ
```

Rotates to the initial angle.

```
Ｗ⁼ ＫＫ«
```

Repeats as long as the current square is a space.

```
    *
```

Prints an asterisk and moves forward in the current direction.

```
    ¿¬ＫＫ«
```

If the cursor moved outside of the original oblong,

```
        ↷²¶*
```

Rotate the direction, then print a newline (which conveniently takes us back to the previous square) and an asterisk, which moves in the new direction.

```
        ¿¬ＫＫ«
```

If the cursor moved back outside of the original oblong,

```
            ↷²¶↷²*
```

Take the cursor back to the previous square, then rotate again, thus printing the asterisk in the other direction.

```
            ¿¬ＫＫ«
```

If the cursor is still outside of the oblong, we must be at a corner.

```
                ↷²¶
```

So go back to the previous square and give up.

```
»»»»+
```

When we can't move any more, print a "+" sign and stop.

Comment: Nice! [Here](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9nq3v96x/v2cdECm837MKwnrUth3M2P6ocY/CoeXv96x@v2fJoZ2P2iY9atxwaLXWof2H1mAKA3Ud2nRoG35ZMIVfyaHdEKj9/7@RoY65jqmOsY4pAA "Charcoal – Try It Online")'s a TIO for those that want to try it.

Comment: @BruceForte Thanks, but I didn't want to link to TIO until I had a solution using `Peek()` (which I do now).

Comment: Oops, `Peek` works again now

Answer (score 2):

## Desmos Calculator - Non Competing to Help Further Knowledge

[Try it online!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/0lhvergrv0)

**Inputs:**

```
X as X position to Start
Y as Y position to Start
s as slope -> -1 for dX/dY = -1, +1 for dX/dY = +1
h as height of box, with 0-indexing
w as width of box, with 0-indexing
```

**Intermediates:**

```
Let b = gcd(h,w),  
Let c = |b-(X-sY)%2b| Or |b-mod(X-sY,2b)|
```

- **gcd(h,w)** represents the [greatest common denominator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor)
- **A % B**, as in Javascript, or **mod(A,B)**, as in Fortran, represents the [modulus operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation), on the interval [0,B).

**Formula, abbreviated:**

```
(|b-(x+y)%2b|-c)(|b-(x-y)%2b|-c)=0
```

**Outputs:**

```
x as x position, 0-indexed, where the ball will land when released
y as y position, 0-indexed, where the ball will land when released
```

**How it Works:**

```
(|b-(x+y)%2b|-c)*(|b-(x-y)%2b|-c)=0
                ^ OR operation - |b-(x+y)%2b|-c=0 or |b-(x-y)%2b|-c=0
|b-(x+/-y)%2b|-c = 0
|b-(x+/-y)%2b| = c
|b-(x+/-y)%2b| = c means (b-(x+/-y))%2b = + or -c 
b-(x+/-y)%2b = +/- c -> b +/- c = (x+/-y)%2b -> (x+/-y) = n*2*b + b +/- c 
Where n is integer.  This will force patterns to repeat every 2b steps in x and y.  
Initial pattern n=0: (x +/- y) = b +/- c -> y = +/- x + b +/- c
In the x positive and y positive plane only, these correspond to lines of positive and 
negative slope, set at intercept b, offset by c on either side.
```

Program fails to meet final criterion - stopping at intersection point and marking with a +, so is submitted as non-competitive for information to help others complete the challenge.  Note that to get Desmos to work when c = 0 or c=b, a small offset factor of 0.01 was introduced, as Desmos seems to have bounds of Mod(A,B) of (0,B) instead of [0,B)

Comment: I suppose you have seen [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48531/ascii-doodling-laser-in-a-box)?

Comment: Actually, I self nerd sniped and lost about 4 days of my at-home time.  I really, really liked this problem.

Comment: You're welcome ;P Also, [relevant](https://xkcd.com/356/).

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>293</s> 279 bytes

```python
w,h,x,y,i,j=map(int,input().split());x-=1;y-=1;l=[x[::]for x in[[' ']*w]*h]
while 1:
 a,b=((x,i)in[(0,-1),(w-1,1)]),((y,j)in[(0,-1),(h-1,1)])
 if a and b or l[y][x]!=' ':l[y][x]='+';break
 i,j=i*(-a*2+1),j*(-b*2+1);l[y][x]='*';x+=i;y+=j
print('\n'.join([''.join(x) for x in l]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU9BbsQgDLzzCvcEJM6qdA@VgngJy4Gou8IpS6I0q8DrU7pKqx5sjzUjj2cua5jSed83DJixIOFo7n4WlFakND9WIU9fc6Q6pc6dUbr8tGhstn3vbtMCGShZy4G7ZnNNcGwLFK@gegYeByNERpJVIl6xUxLF1ilU0lUkCo7/mXAwDOgGHnz6gAGqQ7TF2exeTDXpj8XwluthufrPqq5PUyM637y19c5Y4fCE@k/ccJ1bQ7q0ZmTzUuMJfkn8NE6UhOUHyBJ@E0F0UrJ9f4czqGd16hs)

Comment: Nice! You can save a few bytes by shortening `fx,fy` and replacing `True` by something like `1`, see [here](https://tio.run/##TY/RToUwDIbveYp6tQ7KiTsaTQ7Zk8xdjMiRIg6CGLanx3okxqRJv6Z//vaf89pP8WHfN@opUSamwX6EGTmuxHH@WlGfPueRpetGBDbVhnJtmtE6p0D5coPrtAADR1hCfOuw177Yeh47MJcCArUWMRFrjg7vqTaacBMTo70QZhr@b/pjUwBfIUCIr9CC@I8ue5f8nZWbl2OwqlJNu3ThXdTyN5dYh/Jcic8g2N6w@ROX6jdAxZSroZgXyYjqJarTMHFEpw5I@pYo/SQavdb7fjbwDE/wCLWR@gY)

Comment: @BruceForte thanks! I forgot to replace these.

Comment: [-13 bytes](https://tio.run/##TU9LbsMgEN37FNMVH4@r0iwqGXESwgIrRkAtHCFXhtM7pHKqbkZv9H4z97r5NV2O4zY7cHRHjwUrBoxs7KAMSsj6HIvSRY@jcWuGAiFpTYAYvhvuTQe7D8sMojnA4qQoLRhYE9EPHARDug8CBTMN0dqS/zH@ZJozOLBg0w0maCWLrkYX86Zaz3guivRETnm23085RhU4HSz/7FtSbHD6hfJPzYksvQqy9ip2kOftJydyTeQ9riFRTU5QGLzegsWw455D2qijXwgXBPGa7V52PAA) by turning it into a function.

Comment: Wait, just seen how old this question is... Yet I got here from HNQ...